# design a random(5) using random(7)

Tags: random, probability

Given a random number generator random(7) which can generate number 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 in equal probability(i.e., the probability of each number occurs is 1/7). Now we want to design a random(5) which can generate 1,2,3,4,5 in equal probability(1/5).

There is one way: every time we run random(7), only return when it generates 1-5. If it is 6 or 7, run again until it is 1-5.

I am a little confused. The first question is:

How to proof the probability of each number occurs is 1/5 in mathematical way? 
For example, assume probability of returned number 1 is P(1). If B means 'the selected number is in 1-5' and A means 'select 1', then according to conditional probability, P(1) = P(A|B) = P(AB) / P(B). Obviously P(B) is 5/7. But if P(1)=1/5, P(AB) should be 1/7, why? I think P(A)=1/7. Is there anywhere wrong?

The second question is, this method will run until random(7) not return 6 or 7. What if it runs for a long time not returning 1-5? I know the chance is very very small but is there any way to prevent it?

Thanks!

Comment: You can scale every number by a constant factor (5 / 7), and then round up to get the final result between 1-5.

Comment: @Coldspeed that would be biased.

Comment: @JohnColeman I believe you're right. Does it skew uniform distribution towards the left?

Comment: @Coldspeed `[math.ceil(i*5/7) for i in range(1,8)]` evaluates to `[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5]`. The numbers `3` and `5` would on average each appear twice as often as the other numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability to roll a number **n(1..5)** with a **rnd(7)** are **1/7** in each roll.
The chance to get such a number in the first roll are 5/7, or: in **2/7 of all first-roll cases, you need to roll again**.

This results in a **series**, when examining the probability that a certain number n(1..5) is rolled:

**p(n) = 1/7 + 2/7 * (1/7 + 2/7 * (1/7 + 2/7 * (...)))**

This series evaluates to **1/5**, and that's the expected probability to roll a specific number n(1..5).

Second question: there is a chance that you need to roll eternally. The probability to have a result in x rolls is **1-(2/7)^x**, this quickly approaches 1, so you're **very likely to get a result in just a few rolls, but without guarantee**. The probability to still not have a result in a large number of rolls becomes smaller than the probability C'thulu swallowing the planet in the next 5 minues, so it's not necessary to build in some prevention. If you absolutely must, then return 1 after n internal rolls, this only slightly skews the distribution of the random numbers produced.

Comment: @helen If these answers helped you, consider accepting one of them. They're both really good.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your first question is given by basic conditional probability:

Let `X` be the random(7) number then for any `k` in `{1,2,3,4,5}`:

```
P(X = k | X <= 5) = P(X = k)/P(X <= 5) = (1/7)/(5/7) = 1/5
```

This follows from the observation that the intersection of the 2 events `X = k` and `X <= 5` is simply `X = k`.

The number of trials until the first success (where a success is getting a number <= 5) is a geometric random variable with `p = 5/7`. The expected number of trials is `1/p = 7/5 = 1.4`. You will get a success sooner rather than later in this set up. As @PeterWalser said in his answer, the chance of not quickly getting a number in the range 1-5 is vanishingly small.

For fun you can write a short script to investigate it. Here is one in Python:

```
from random import randint
from collections import Counter

def trials_needed():
    num = randint(1,7)
    trial = 1
    while num > 5:
        num = randint(1,7)
        trial += 1
    return trial

counts = Counter(trials_needed() for i in range(10**6))
for c,i in counts.items(): print(c,":",i)
```

Output from a typical run:

```
1 : 714212
2 : 204141
3 : 58340
4 : 16515
5 : 4814
6 : 1456
7 : 347
8 : 133
9 : 28
10 : 10
11 : 4
```

Over 99% of the time less than 5 trials are needed. More than 10 trials is extremely rare.